# How quickly do these fertilizers get used up?

Tags: vegetables, fertilizer

I had my veggie garden soil tested last year and followed the university extension recommendations by adding nitrogen (blood meal) and potassium (sul-po-mag).  So far, the plants have responded well and things are growing quite nicely.
As I plan for next year, how likely is it that I will need a similar amount of amendments?  Will some of what I added remain or will my chard/lettuce/tomato/cucumber/beets deplete it completely?

Comment: one approach (which gets expensive, unless soil tests are heavily subsidized in your locale) is to make soil testing an annual event... *e.g.*  painless if it's $15/test, painful if it's $150/test (IMHO - your pain/$ threshold may vary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will most likely need to refresh the soil as you have done this year. cucumbers specifically are very heavy feeders so you might need to do a full replenish there. for lettuce or beets maybe half of what you did this year would work since the nutrients (some) would remain as they are less demanding plants.